# Powered by Odoo footer

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I need to change the "Powered" in "Powered by Odoo" footer to "Made",
So the footer of my Odoo (Formerly OpenERP) Version 8.0-aab3d9f will be "Made by Odoo"

any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First go to your Odoo web module and open below file.

```
addons => web => views => webclient_templates.xml
```

Now find this tag `<div class="oe_footer">` and edit it like

```
<div class="oe_footer">
    Made by <a href="http://www.openerp.com" target="_blank"><span>Odoo</span></a>
</div>
```

Save it and refresh your browser. Hope you get what you want.

Comment: It`s not working for me,

can you tell me the webclient_templates.xml file is responsible for what URL, is it for "localhost:8069/web?db=..." ??

Comment: have do above changes in that file? if yes, than restart your server and upgrade `web module` from the GUI.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i upgrade web module from the GUI?? is it the "Apply Scheduled Upgrades" option?? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: go to `Setting => Modules => Local Modules` and right side search box hit with `web` that will give web module and than do upgrade.

Comment: Hi @Odedra I did as requested 'Setting => Modules => Local Modules'  but when i search web I only get website builder   I am using odoo version 8

Comment: strange, it must be their. check out your path of modules. might be that will be help to you.

Comment: The correct action is extend the template web.menu_secondary

Answer (score 17):

Instead of changing directly in the core of odoo (which is not appreciated), you can create a new module that depends on *web* module.
Then you can extend template ***web.menu_secondary*** from *webclient_templates.xml* in web module, like this:

-> _ _openerp__.py file:

```
{
    'name': "My Module",

     # for the full list
    'category': 'Web',

    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['web'],

    # always loaded
    'data': ['templates.xml'],
    'demo': [],
}
```

-> templates.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <template id="menu_secondary" inherit_id="web.menu_secondary">
        <div class="oe_footer" position="replace">
            <div class="oe_footer">
                Made by <a href="http://www.odoo.com" target="_blank"><span>Odoo</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML Editor of the Website module to change your site's copyright footer:

```
Customize > HTML Editor
```

Website HTML Editor Footer Copyright

[image: Website HTML Editor Footer Copyright]

As this is a fast and clean way to accomplish what you're asking for, though changes will be saved directly to working database. If you want to replicate your changes in different databases, the best approach is to make a custom module.