# Odoo 9 change login page title and "powered by" link

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

How do i change this "Odoo" login page title and also the "powered by" link .I am using Odoo 9 community edition.

[title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz42l.png)

[Powered by link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exFwJ.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powered by Odoo footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27780253/powered-by-odoo-footer)

Comment: i edited that line and refreshed my browser.still no effect

Comment: all what you need to change is in web module  you can extend web template and update what you need